# Can i store an selected value in variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to store an select value into an variable? in codeigniter. 
Something like this:

```
   $this->db->select_max('Datum');
        $this->db->from('Uren');
        $this->db->join('Project','Project.idProject = Uren.idProject');

 $test123 = $this->db->get();
```

So that i get the value of the `select_max` into the variable `$test123`

Comment: What are you trying to do? I dont get it

Comment: Trying to get the value of the select_max. and store it into the variable test

Comment: Well, you can technically store everything in a variable if you retrieve it correctly. Maybe I'm too tired.

Answer (score 2):

The proprer way, then $max will contain the max of your request, or FALSE if request is not valid :

```
$query = $this->db->select_max('Uren.Datum', 'max_Datum')->get('your_table');      
$max = $query ? $query->row()->max_Datum : FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something like this.

```
$this->db->select_max('Uren.Datum');
$test = $this->db->get('table_name');

if ($test) {
    $this->db->select('fields');
    $this->db->group_by('Project.idProject');
    $this->db->get('table_name');
}
```

these will be two separate quires.

Comment: $test will contain TRUE or FALSE, depending on request error. But it will not contain the max of the table.

Comment: Yes thats true @VincentDecaux but how can contain the $test with the max of the table?

Comment: Just with : $test->row()->Datum;

Comment: i've edited my answer could you take a look at it where im wrong

Comment: I have fixed it :) for someone who has the same question Look at the answer i added

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$this->db->select_max('field_name');
$check_query = $this->db->get('table_name');
if ($check_query->num_rows() > 0) {
$max = $check_query->result();
if(!empty($max[0]->field_name)) {
}
}
```

for more :- https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that worked to my question. Hope it will help someone else too

```
    $this->db->select_max('Datum');
                        $this->db->from('Uren');
        $this->db->join('Project','Project.idProject = Uren.idProject');
        if ($idKlant > 0){
        $this->db->where('idKlant', $idKlant);}
            $datumstart = $this->db->get();
foreach ($datumstart->result() as $row)
{
    $datastart = $row->Datum;
}
```